# How to make table caption visible?

Tags: html, css

I have a table with a caption aligned to the bottom of the table. The table has many rows. The problem is that the caption is only visible when I scroll the table all the way to the bottom. How to make it visible regardless the number of rows and whether it needs a scrollbar or not?

http://jsfiddle.net/h7qbvdrb/

Do I need a new div or something like that??

```
<div id="guid-4e344777-bb3a-4732-b4a0-4744920e6d66" class="content r-table item-3 ui-draggable ui-resizable" style="position: absolute; width: 147px; height: 540px; left: 425px; top: 46px; opacity: 1;"><div class="table selected" style="overflow-y: scroll; overflow-x: visible; width: 100%; height: 100%; z-index: 3;"><table class="qtable style-97ba0187-37c0-47a1-a4ad-31b0f5281e77-1-_-_ exportarea" id="T4e344777-bb3a-4732-b4a0-4744920e6d66" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width: 100%; height: 507px;">
  <caption align="bottom" class="footer"><div data-editable="true" style="font-family:'Open Sans', sans-serif;font-size:8pt;font-weight:normal;font-style:normal;text-decoration:none;color:#505050;text-align:center;">Age RAW DATA<br>
sample size = 327</div></caption>
<tbody class="" style="-webkit-user-select: none;"><tr class="first-header-row last-header-row header-row"><th class="topLeft"><div class="statisticsInHeader"><span class="statname">Values</span></div></th><th class="colHeader colHeader-0 col-even numberDataHeader lastCol ui-draggable"><div>Age</div><div class="drag-grabber"></div></th></tr>
<tr class="row-0 row-even data single-series"><th class="rowHeader rowHeader-0 ui-draggable" title="18 to 24">1<div class="drag-grabber"></div></th><td class="value cell cell-0-0 col-0 col-even lastCol" style="">27.00</td></tr>
<tr class="row-1 row-odd data single-series"><th class="rowHeader rowHeader-1 ui-draggable" title="25 to 29">2<div class="drag-grabber"></div></th><td class="value cell cell-1-0 col-0 col-even lastCol" style="">47.00</td></tr>
<tr class="row-2 row-even data single-series"><th class="rowHeader rowHeader-2 ui-draggable" title="30 to 34">3<div class="drag-grabber"></div></th><td class="value cell cell-2-0 col-0 col-even lastCol" style="">27.00</td></tr>
<tr class="row-3 row-odd data single-series"><th class="rowHeader rowHeader-3 ui-draggable" title="35 to 39">4<div class="drag-grabber"></div></th><td class="value cell cell-3-0 col-0 col-even lastCol" style="">27.00</td></tr>
<tr class="row-4 row-even data single-series"><th class="rowHeader rowHeader-4 ui-draggable" title="40 to 44">5<div class="drag-grabber"></div></th><td class="value cell cell-4-0 col-0 col-even lastCol" style="">60.00</td></tr>
<tr class="row-5 row-odd data single-series"><th class="rowHeader rowHeader-5 ui-draggable" title="45 to 49">6<div class="drag-grabber"></div></th><td class="value cell cell-5-0 col-0 col-even lastCol" style="">60.00</td></tr>
<tr class="row-6 row-even data single-series"><th class="rowHeader rowHeader-6 ui-draggable" title="50 to 54">7<div class="drag-grabber"></div></th><td class="value cell cell-6-0 col-0 col-even lastCol" style="">52.00</td></tr>
<tr class="row-7 row-odd data single-series"><th class="rowHeader rowHeader-7 ui-draggable" title="55 to 64">8<div class="drag-grabber"></div></th><td class="value cell cell-7-0 col-0 col-even lastCol" style="">37.00</td></tr>
<tr class="row-8 row-even data single-series"><th class="rowHeader rowHeader-8 ui-draggable" title="65 or more">9<div class="drag-grabber"></div></th><td class="value cell cell-8-0 col-0 col-even lastCol" style="">77.00</td></tr>
<tr class="row-9 row-odd data single-series"><th class="rowHeader rowHeader-9 ui-draggable" title="18 to 24 or 25 to 29 or 30 to 34 or 35 to 39 or 40 to 44 or 45 to 49 or 50 to 54 or 55 to 64 or 65 or more">10<div class="drag-grabber"></div></th><td class="value cell cell-9-0 col-0 col-even lastCol" style="">47.00</td></tr>
<tr class="row-10 row-even data single-series"><th class="rowHeader rowHeader-10 ui-draggable">11<div class="drag-grabber"></div></th><td class="value cell cell-10-0 col-0 col-even lastCol" style="">47.00</td></tr>
<tr class="row-11 row-odd data single-series"><th class="rowHeader rowHeader-11 ui-draggable">12<div class="drag-grabber"></div></th><td class="value cell cell-11-0 col-0 col-even lastCol" style="">60.00</td></tr>
<tr class="row-12 row-even data single-series"><th class="rowHeader rowHeader-12 ui-draggable">13<div class="drag-grabber"></div></th><td class="value cell cell-12-0 col-0 col-even lastCol" style="">60.00</td></tr>
<tr class="row-13 row-odd data single-series"><th class="rowHeader rowHeader-13 ui-draggable">14<div class="drag-grabber"></div></th><td class="value cell cell-13-0 col-0 col-even lastCol" style="">32.00</td></tr>
<tr class="row-14 row-even data single-series"><th class="rowHeader rowHeader-14 ui-draggable">15<div class="drag-grabber"></div></th><td class="value cell cell-14-0 col-0 col-even lastCol" style="">77.00</td></tr>
<tr class="row-15 row-odd data single-series"><th class="rowHeader rowHeader-15 ui-draggable">16<div class="drag-grabber"></div></th><td class="value cell cell-15-0 col-0 col-even lastCol" style="">27.00</td></tr>
<tr class="row-16 row-even data single-series"><th class="rowHeader rowHeader-16 ui-draggable">17<div class="drag-grabber"></div></th><td class="value cell cell-16-0 col-0 col-even lastCol" style="">32.00</td></tr>
<tr class="row-17 row-odd data single-series"><th class="rowHeader rowHeader-17 ui-draggable">18<div class="drag-grabber"></div></th><td class="value cell cell-17-0 col-0 col-even lastCol" style="">52.00</td></tr>
<tr class="row-18 row-even data single-series"><th class="rowHeader rowHeader-18 ui-draggable">19<div class="drag-grabber"></div></th><td class="value cell cell-18-0 col-0 col-even lastCol" style="">37.00</td></tr>
<tr class="row-19 row-odd data single-series"><th class="rowHeader rowHeader-19 ui-draggable">20<div class="drag-grabber"></div></th><td class="value cell cell-19-0 col-0 col-even lastCol" style="">21.00</td></tr>
<tr class="row-20 row-even data single-series"><th class="rowHeader rowHeader-20 ui-draggable">21<div class="drag-grabber"></div></th><td class="value cell cell-20-0 col-0 col-even lastCol" style="">52.00</td></tr>
<tr class="row-21 row-odd data single-series"><th class="rowHeader rowHeader-21 ui-draggable">22<div class="drag-grabber"></div></th><td class="value cell cell-21-0 col-0 col-even lastCol" style="">47.00</td></tr>
<tr class="row-22 row-even data single-series"><th class="rowHeader rowHeader-22 ui-draggable">23<div class="drag-grabber"></div></th><td class="value cell cell-22-0 col-0 col-even lastCol" style="">60.00</td></tr>
<tr class="row-23 row-odd data single-series"><th class="rowHeader rowHeader-23 ui-draggable">24<div class="drag-grabber"></div></th><td class="value cell cell-23-0 col-0 col-even lastCol" style="">52.00</td></tr>
<tr class="row-24 row-even data single-series"><th class="rowHeader rowHeader-24 ui-draggable">25<div class="drag-grabber"></div></th><td class="value cell cell-24-0 col-0 col-even lastCol" style="">32.00</td></tr>
<tr class="row-25 row-odd data single-series"><th class="rowHeader rowHeader-25 ui-draggable">26<div class="drag-grabber"></div></th><td class="value cell cell-25-0 col-0 col-even lastCol" style="">27.00</td></tr>
<tr class="row-26 row-even data single-series"><th class="rowHeader rowHeader-26 ui-draggable">27<div class="drag-grabber"></div></th><td class="value cell cell-26-0 col-0 col-even lastCol" style="">37.00</td></tr>
<tr class="row-27 row-odd data single-series"><th class="rowHeader rowHeader-27 ui-draggable">28<div class="drag-grabber"></div></th><td class="value cell cell-27-0 col-0 col-even lastCol" style="">42.00</td></tr>
<tr class="row-28 row-even data single-series"><th class="rowHeader rowHeader-28 ui-draggable">29<div class="drag-grabber"></div></th><td class="value cell cell-28-0 col-0 col-even lastCol" style="">27.00</td></tr>
<tr class="row-29 row-odd data single-series"><th class="rowHeader rowHeader-29 ui-draggable">30<div class="drag-grabber"></div></th><td class="value cell cell-29-0 col-0 col-even lastCol" style="">60.00</td></tr>
<tr class="row-30 row-even data single-series"><th class="rowHeader rowHeader-30 ui-draggable">31<div class="drag-grabber"></div></th><td class="value cell cell-30-0 col-0 col-even lastCol" style="">52.00</td></tr>
<tr class="row-31 row-odd data single-series"><th class="rowHeader rowHeader-31 ui-draggable">32<div class="drag-grabber"></div></th><td class="value cell cell-31-0 col-0 col-even lastCol" style="">60.00</td></tr>
<tr class="row-32 row-even data single-series"><th class="rowHeader rowHeader-32 ui-draggable">33<div class="drag-grabber"></div></th><td class="value cell cell-32-0 col-0 col-even lastCol" style="">32.00</td></tr>
<tr class="row-33 row-odd data single-series"><th class="rowHeader rowHeader-33 ui-draggable">34<div class="drag-grabber"></div></th><td class="value cell cell-33-0 col-0 col-even lastCol" style="">21.00</td></tr>
<tr class="row-34 row-even data single-series"><th class="rowHeader rowHeader-34 ui-draggable">35<div class="drag-grabber"></div></th><td class="value cell cell-34-0 col-0 col-even lastCol" style="">60.00</td></tr>
<tr class="row-35 row-odd data single-series"><th class="rowHeader rowHeader-35 ui-draggable">36<div class="drag-grabber"></div></th><td class="value cell cell-35-0 col-0 col-even lastCol" style="">32.00</td></tr>
<tr class="row-36 row-even data single-series"><th class="rowHeader rowHeader-36 ui-draggable">37<div class="drag-grabber"></div></th><td class="value cell cell-36-0 col-0 col-even lastCol" style="">60.00</td></tr>
<tr class="row-37 row-odd data single-series"><th class="rowHeader rowHeader-37 ui-draggable">38<div class="drag-grabber"></div></th><td class="value cell cell-37-0 col-0 col-even lastCol" style="">47.00</td></tr>
<tr class="row-38 row-even data single-series"><th class="rowHeader rowHeader-38 ui-draggable">39<div class="drag-grabber"></div></th><td class="value cell cell-38-0 col-0 col-even lastCol" style="">21.00</td></tr>
<tr class="row-39 row-odd data single-series"><th class="rowHeader rowHeader-39 ui-draggable">40<div class="drag-grabber"></div></th><td class="value cell cell-39-0 col-0 col-even lastCol" style="">42.00</td></tr>
<tr class="row-40 row-even data single-series"><th class="rowHeader rowHeader-40 ui-draggable">41<div class="drag-grabber"></div></th><td class="value cell cell-40-0 col-0 col-even lastCol" style="">60.00</td></tr>
<tr class="row-41 row-odd data single-series"><th class="rowHeader rowHeader-41 ui-draggable">42<div class="drag-grabber"></div></th><td class="value cell cell-41-0 col-0 col-even lastCol" style="">47.00</td></tr>
<tr class="row-42 row-even data single-series"><th class="rowHeader rowHeader-42 ui-draggable">43<div class="drag-grabber"></div></th><td class="value cell cell-42-0 col-0 col-even lastCol" style="">60.00</td></tr>
<tr class="row-43 row-odd data single-series"><th class="rowHeader rowHeader-43 ui-draggable">44<div class="drag-grabber"></div></th><td class="value cell cell-43-0 col-0 col-even lastCol" style="">42.00</td></tr>
<tr class="row-44 row-even data single-series"><th class="rowHeader rowHeader-44 ui-draggable">45<div class="drag-grabber"></div></th><td class="value cell cell-44-0 col-0 col-even lastCol" style="">47.00</td></tr>
<tr class="row-45 row-odd data single-series"><th class="rowHeader rowHeader-45 ui-draggable">46<div class="drag-grabber"></div></th><td class="value cell cell-45-0 col-0 col-even lastCol" style="">27.00</td></tr>
<tr class="row-46 row-even data single-series"><th class="rowHeader rowHeader-46 ui-draggable">47<div class="drag-grabber"></div></th><td class="value cell cell-46-0 col-0 col-even lastCol" style="">37.00</td></tr>
<tr class="row-47 row-odd data single-series"><th class="rowHeader rowHeader-47 ui-draggable">48<div class="drag-grabber"></div></th><td class="value cell cell-47-0 col-0 col-even lastCol" style="">42.00</td></tr>
<tr class="row-48 row-even data single-series"><th class="rowHeader rowHeader-48 ui-draggable">49<div class="drag-grabber"></div></th><td class="value cell cell-48-0 col-0 col-even lastCol" style="">42.00</td></tr>
<tr class="row-49 row-odd data single-series"><th class="rowHeader rowHeader-49 ui-draggable">50<div class="drag-grabber"></div></th><td class="value cell cell-49-0 col-0 col-even lastCol" style="">47.00</td></tr>
<tr class="row-50 row-even data single-series"><th class="rowHeader rowHeader-50 ui-draggable">51<div class="drag-grabber"></div></th><td class="value cell cell-50-0 col-0 col-even lastCol" style="">21.00</td></tr>
<tr class="row-51 row-odd data single-series"><th class="rowHeader rowHeader-51 ui-draggable">52<div class="drag-grabber"></div></th><td class="value cell cell-51-0 col-0 col-even lastCol" style="">60.00</td></tr>
<tr class="row-52 row-even data single-series"><th class="rowHeader rowHeader-52 ui-draggable">53<div class="drag-grabber"></div></th><td class="value cell cell-52-0 col-0 col-even lastCol" style="">37.00</td></tr>
<tr class="row-53 row-odd data single-series"><th class="rowHeader rowHeader-53 ui-draggable">54<div class="drag-grabber"></div></th><td class="value cell cell-53-0 col-0 col-even lastCol" style="">27.00</td></tr>
<tr class="row-54 row-even data single-series"><th class="rowHeader rowHeader-54 ui-draggable">55<div class="drag-grabber"></div></th><td class="value cell cell-54-0 col-0 col-even lastCol" style="">42.00</td></tr>
<tr class="row-55 row-odd data single-series"><th class="rowHeader rowHeader-55 ui-draggable">56<div class="drag-grabber"></div></th><td class="value cell cell-55-0 col-0 col-even lastCol" style="">32.00</td></tr>
<tr class="row-56 row-even data single-series"><th class="rowHeader rowHeader-56 ui-draggable">57<div class="drag-grabber"></div></th><td class="value cell cell-56-0 col-0 col-even lastCol" style="">60.00</td></tr>
<tr class="row-57 row-odd data single-series"><th class="rowHeader rowHeader-57 ui-draggable">58<div class="drag-grabber"></div></th><td class="value cell cell-57-0 col-0 col-even lastCol" style="">32.00</td></tr>
<tr class="row-58 row-even data single-series"><th class="rowHeader rowHeader-58 ui-draggable">59<div class="drag-grabber"></div></th><td class="value cell cell-58-0 col-0 col-even lastCol" style="">77.00</td></tr>
<tr class="row-59 row-odd data single-series"><th class="rowHeader rowHeader-59 ui-draggable">60<div class="drag-grabber"></div></th><td class="value cell cell-59-0 col-0 col-even lastCol" style="">21.00</td></tr>
<tr class="row-60 row-even data single-series"><th class="rowHeader rowHeader-60 ui-draggable">61<div class="drag-grabber"></div></th><td class="value cell cell-60-0 col-0 col-even lastCol" style="">37.00</td></tr>
<tr class="row-61 row-odd data single-series"><th class="rowHeader rowHeader-61 ui-draggable">62<div class="drag-grabber"></div></th><td class="value cell cell-61-0 col-0 col-even lastCol" style="">42.00</td></tr>
<tr class="row-62 row-even data single-series"><th class="rowHeader rowHeader-62 ui-draggable">63<div class="drag-grabber"></div></th><td class="value cell cell-62-0 col-0 col-even lastCol" style="">21.00</td></tr>
<tr class="row-63 row-odd data single-series"><th class="rowHeader rowHeader-63 ui-draggable">64<div class="drag-grabber"></div></th><td class="value cell cell-63-0 col-0 col-even lastCol" style="">47.00</td></tr>
<tr class="row-64 row-even data single-series"><th class="rowHeader rowHeader-64 ui-draggable">65<div class="drag-grabber"></div></th><td class="value cell cell-64-0 col-0 col-even lastCol" style="">21.00</td></tr>
<tr class="row-65 row-odd data single-series"><th class="rowHeader rowHeader-65 ui-draggable">66<div class="drag-grabber"></div></th><td class="value cell cell-65-0 col-0 col-even lastCol" style="">32.00</td></tr>
<tr class="row-66 row-even data single-series"><th class="rowHeader rowHeader-66 ui-draggable">67<div class="drag-grabber"></div></th><td class="value cell cell-66-0 col-0 col-even lastCol" style="">77.00</td></tr>
<tr class="row-67 row-odd data single-series"><th class="rowHeader rowHeader-67 ui-draggable">68<div class="drag-grabber"></div></th><td class="value cell cell-67-0 col-0 col-even lastCol" style="">37.00</td></tr>
<tr class="row-68 row-even data single-series"><th class="rowHeader rowHeader-68 ui-draggable">69<div class="drag-grabber"></div></th><td class="value cell cell-68-0 col-0 col-even lastCol" style="">27.00</td></tr>
<tr class="row-69 row-odd data single-series"><th class="rowHeader rowHeader-69 ui-draggable">70<div class="drag-grabber"></div></th><td class="value cell cell-69-0 col-0 col-even lastCol" style="">37.00</td></tr>
<tr class="row-70 row-even data single-series"><th class="rowHeader rowHeader-70 ui-draggable">71<div class="drag-grabber"></div></th><td class="value cell cell-70-0 col-0 col-even lastCol" style="">37.00</td></tr>
<tr class="row-71 row-odd data single-series"><th class="rowHeader rowHeader-71 ui-draggable">72<div class="drag-grabber"></div></th><td class="value cell cell-71-0 col-0 col-even lastCol" style="">21.00</td></tr>
<tr class="row-72 row-even data single-series"><th class="rowHeader rowHeader-72 ui-draggable">73<div class="drag-grabber"></div></th><td class="value cell cell-72-0 col-0 col-even lastCol" style="">32.00</td></tr>
<tr class="row-73 row-odd data single-series"><th class="rowHeader rowHeader-73 ui-draggable">74<div class="drag-grabber"></div></th><td class="value cell cell-73-0 col-0 col-even lastCol" style="">42.00</td></tr>
<tr class="row-74 row-even data single-series"><th class="rowHeader rowHeader-74 ui-draggable">75<div class="drag-grabber"></div></th><td class="value cell cell-74-0 col-0 col-even lastCol" style="">47.00</td></tr>
<tr class="row-75 row-odd data single-series"><th class="rowHeader rowHeader-75 ui-draggable">76<div class="drag-grabber"></div></th><td class="value cell cell-75-0 col-0 col-even lastCol" style="">52.00</td></tr>
<tr class="row-76 row-even data single-series"><th class="rowHeader rowHeader-76 ui-draggable">77<div class="drag-grabber"></div></th><td class="value cell cell-76-0 col-0 col-even lastCol" style="">42.00</td></tr>
<tr class="row-77 row-odd data single-series"><th class="rowHeader rowHeader-77 ui-draggable">78<div class="drag-grabber"></div></th><td class="value cell cell-77-0 col-0 col-even lastCol" style="">60.00</td></tr>
<tr class="row-78 row-even data single-series"><th class="rowHeader rowHeader-78 ui-draggable">79<div class="drag-grabber"></div></th><td class="value cell cell-78-0 col-0 col-even lastCol" style="">60.00</td></tr>
<tr class="row-79 row-odd data single-series"><th class="rowHeader rowHeader-79 ui-draggable">80<div class="drag-grabber"></div></th><td class="value cell cell-79-0 col-0 col-even lastCol" style="">77.00</td></tr>
<tr class="row-80 row-even data single-series"><th class="rowHeader rowHeader-80 ui-draggable">81<div class="drag-grabber"></div></th><td class="value cell cell-80-0 col-0 col-even lastCol" style="">52.00</td></tr>
<tr class="row-81 row-odd data single-series"><th class="rowHeader rowHeader-81 ui-draggable">82<div class="drag-grabber"></div></th><td class="value cell cell-81-0 col-0 col-even lastCol" style="">32.00</td></tr>
<tr class="row-82 row-even data single-series"><th class="rowHeader rowHeader-82 ui-draggable">83<div class="drag-grabber"></div></th><td class="value cell cell-82-0 col-0 col-even lastCol" style="">37.00</td></tr>
<tr class="row-83 row-odd data single-series"><th class="rowHeader rowHeader-83 ui-draggable">84<div class="drag-grabber"></div></th><td class="value cell cell-83-0 col-0 col-even lastCol" style="">21.00</td></tr>
<tr class="row-84 row-even data single-series"><th class="rowHeader rowHeader-84 ui-draggable">85<div class="drag-grabber"></div></th><td class="value cell cell-84-0 col-0 col-even lastCol" style="">27.00</td></tr>
<tr class="row-85 row-odd data single-series"><th class="rowHeader rowHeader-85 ui-draggable">86<div class="drag-grabber"></div></th><td class="value cell cell-85-0 col-0 col-even lastCol" style="">21.00</td></tr>
<tr class="row-210 row-even data single-series"><th class="rowHeader rowHeader-210 ui-draggable">211<div class="drag-grabber"></div></th><td class="value cell cell-210-0 col-0 col-even lastCol" style="">60.00</td></tr>
<tr class="row-320 row-even data single-series"><th class="rowHeader rowHeader-320 ui-draggable">321<div class="drag-grabber"></div></th><td class="value cell cell-320-0 col-0 col-even lastCol" style="">32.00</td></tr>
<tr class="row-321 row-odd data single-series"><th class="rowHeader rowHeader-321 ui-draggable">322<div class="drag-grabber"></div></th><td class="value cell cell-321-0 col-0 col-even lastCol" style="">32.00</td></tr>
<tr class="row-322 row-even data single-series"><th class="rowHeader rowHeader-322 ui-draggable">323<div class="drag-grabber"></div></th><td class="value cell cell-322-0 col-0 col-even lastCol" style="">52.00</td></tr>
<tr class="row-323 row-odd data single-series"><th class="rowHeader rowHeader-323 ui-draggable">324<div class="drag-grabber"></div></th><td class="value cell cell-323-0 col-0 col-even lastCol" style="">32.00</td></tr>
<tr class="row-324 row-even data single-series"><th class="rowHeader rowHeader-324 ui-draggable">325<div class="drag-grabber"></div></th><td class="value cell cell-324-0 col-0 col-even lastCol" style="">21.00</td></tr>
<tr class="row-325 row-odd data single-series"><th class="rowHeader rowHeader-325 ui-draggable">326<div class="drag-grabber"></div></th><td class="value cell cell-325-0 col-0 col-even lastCol" style="">32.00</td></tr>
<tr class="row-326 row-even data single-series"><th class="rowHeader rowHeader-326 lastRow ui-draggable">327<div class="drag-grabber"></div></th><td class="value cell cell-326-0 col-0 col-even lastCol lastRow" style="">52.00</td></tr>
</tbody></table>
</div><div class="draggable-bar top-draggable-bar horizontal-draggable-bar move"></div><div class="draggable-bar bottom-draggable-bar horizontal-draggable-bar move"></div><div class="draggable-bar left-draggable-bar vertical-draggable-bar move"></div><div class="draggable-bar right-draggable-bar vertical-draggable-bar move"></div><div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-n" style="z-index: 90; left: 68.99549549549549px;"></div><div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-e" style="z-index: 90; top: 265.4954954954955px;"></div><div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-s" style="z-index: 90; left: 68.99549549549549px;"></div><div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-w" style="z-index: 90; top: 265.4954954954955px;"></div><div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-se ui-icon ui-icon-gripsmall-diagonal-se" style="z-index: 90;"></div><div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-sw" style="z-index: 90;"></div><div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-ne" style="z-index: 90;"></div><div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-nw" style="z-index: 90;"></div></div>
```

Comment: Where you want to show the caption `top` or `bottom`? by default `caption` default value is `top`.

Comment: did you use position:fixed?

Comment: why OP need `fixed` position, its clear table is too long and caption is at the bottom of table, so simple solution is reduce the table `height`.

Comment: @Student T `caption` can be on `top` of table and `bottom` of table using `caption-side: bottom;` and the `top` is default value.

Comment: I need it in the bottom of the table. It's a business requirmeent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this

```
$(function() {
  $('#id').bind('scroll', function() {
    $('.caption').css('display','block');
 })
});


<div class="caption" style="position:fixed;bottom:0px;display:none;">
```

Edited

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#ids').bind('scroll', function() {
    if($(this).scrollTop()){ 
        $('.caption').css('display','block');
    } else { 
        $('.caption').css('display','none'); 
    }
 })
});
</script>
<div id="ids" style="height:100px;width:100px;overflow-y:scroll;border:1px solid #f00;">
<table style="table-layout: fixed">
    <tr ><th class="rowHeader rowHeader-20 ui-draggable">21<div class="drag-grabber"></div></th><td class="value cell cell-20-0 col-0 col-even lastCol" style="">52.00</td></tr>
    <tr ><th class="rowHeader rowHeader-20 ui-draggable">21<div class="drag-grabber"></div></th><td class="value cell cell-20-0 col-0 col-even lastCol" style="">52.00</td></tr>
    <tr ><th class="rowHeader rowHeader-20 ui-draggable">21<div class="drag-grabber"></div></th><td class="value cell cell-20-0 col-0 col-even lastCol" style="">52.00</td></tr>
    <tr ><th class="rowHeader rowHeader-20 ui-draggable">21<div class="drag-grabber"></div></th><td class="value cell cell-20-0 col-0 col-even lastCol" style="">52.00</td></tr>
    <tr ><th class="rowHeader rowHeader-20 ui-draggable">21<div class="drag-grabber"></div></th><td class="value cell cell-20-0 col-0 col-even lastCol" style="">52.00</td></tr>
    <tr ><th class="rowHeader rowHeader-20 ui-draggable">21<div class="drag-grabber"></div></th><td class="value cell cell-20-0 col-0 col-even lastCol" style="">52.00</td></tr>
    <tr ><th class="rowHeader rowHeader-20 ui-draggable">21<div class="drag-grabber"></div></th><td class="value cell cell-20-0 col-0 col-even lastCol" style="">52.00</td></tr>
    <tr ><th class="rowHeader rowHeader-20 ui-draggable">21<div class="drag-grabber"></div></th><td class="value cell cell-20-0 col-0 col-even lastCol" style="">52.00</td></tr>
    <tr style="position: fixed;background-color:grey;top:82px;z-index:-1;display:none;" class="caption"><th>test content</th></caption>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: And add also the condition if($(this).scrollTop()){ $('.caption').css('display','none'); }

Comment: I tried it in JSFiddle but it didn't work... Is that possible for you to fork it in JSFiddle and give me an example? Thanks!

Comment: Use this jquery <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>

Answer (score 0):

just add something like this (of course you can style at will)

```
caption{position:fixed; bottom:0; background:#fff;}
```